# Rspec tests fail even though everything works fine manually

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using RSpec to test my Rails5 app and am having problems regarding deleting or updating objects. That is, the app functions correctly but if I test some of these functions the tests fail.

**Test 1**

```
let!(:user) { create(:user) }
let!(:admin) { create(:admin) }
let!(:new_name) { 'new name' }

it 'changes user name' do
    visit(user_path(user))
    click_on('Edit')
    expect(current_path).to eq(edit_user_as_admin_path(user))
    fill_in('Name', with: new_name)
    click_on('Update')
    expect(current_path).to eq(user_path(user))
    expect(user.name).to eq(new_name)
end
```

If I go through it in my browser as an admin I can update the attributes just fine.

**Test 2**

```
  let!(:user){create(:user)}
  let!(:friend){create(:user)}

  before(:each){sign_in friend
    visit(user_path(user))
    click_on('Add Friend')
    sign_in user
  }

  it 'is accepted' do
    visit(user_path(user))
    click_on('Accept')
    expect(user.friend_requests).to be_empty
 end
```

Here again, if I do it manually and check everything with byebug or rails console the user does not have a `friend_request` anymore. So those two are system specs and I wonder if misunderstood how to test correctly. Since I read system specs test the whole system I thought by simulating the user behaviour I can also check if the controller actions are executed properly.

But also in my model specs it's not working like it should be:

**Test 3**

```
let!(:user){create(:user)}
let!(:post) {create(:post)}

it 'is deleted if user is deleted' do
  user.posts << post
  expect do
    user.destroy
  end.to change(user.posts,:count).by(-1)
end
```

I thought this would be an approproiate test for a model since it should work because of a `dependent: :destroy`.

Now I wonder if I have mistakes in my code that I just can't seem to figure out or if I have a wrong concept in my brain.

Any help and clarification would be appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reload your `user` object, via `user.reload.friend_requests`.  The in-memory object in your test hasn't been hydrated with any updates.

Comment: Thanks! That did it